# Do Access recordset fields() need initializing?

Tags: combobox, recordset

I use the onClick event to get values from a combo box. As here:
Me.ComboSelProject.Recordset.Fields(0).Value
On the first onClick event, no matter what row has been selected, the value is from the first row of the recordset. On subsequent onClick events the value is for the selected row.
The value shown in the face of the combobox is always the correct selected value. IOW comboSelProject.text is always correct.
I've tried to initialize the combobox in the Form_load() procedure using:
Me.ComboSelClient.Value = Me.ComboSelClient.ItemData(0) but this has not helped.
Thanks for any help ...

Comment: I have a crude workaround for this problem. I monitor and manage the first use of the OnClick event for the ComboBox. On first use I tell the user to select the row again ... because of an MS Access bug.

Answer (score 0):

The click event happens before the change event.  If you want to use the new value, use the Change event.

And you should probably try to initialize the .text of the combo box rather than the .value

Comment: The same problem happens with the onChange event. The first onChange event gives the wrong value. Subsequent onChange events give correct values.
Unfortunately the onChange event triggers when the user types into the text property so losing the search function of the combobox.
I tried initializing the text property several ways.  Access complains "The text you entered isn't an item in the list."